# Tomcat in Eclipse: Edit Javascript without redeploying

Tags: javascript, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I am working on a Java application (which runs on Tomcat) using Eclipse WTP. For development I have configured my tomcat server in Eclipse and use the "auto publish" feature.

This works for .java files (compiled files are getting published).

Its also fine for working in jsp. In this case my edited jsp file is just copied to the server directory without redeploying my application.

However it does not work with javascript files. Everytime i change a .js file my application is redeployed and i have to wait a few seconds.

Is there any tomcat option i am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doubleclick your server in the servers view, click on the tab *modules* at the lower bound of the servers property window, select your web module from the list, click the edit button, uncheck "auto reloading enabled", click ok, save your settings and restart the server.